# silverlight wcf service prompt for credentials

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight app that calls a wcf service, and I'm having trouble deploying it.

I can publish the files, but when the app tries to access the service, it doesnt seem to get anything back.

The app is set for client credentials with Windows Authentication

What's weird is that its not throwing errors. The silverlight app just seems to stop with a blank screen.

To test the deployed service, I try to access it from a browser, and I'm prompted for credentials. I try putting in my name and password, but it just asks me for credentials again.

What credentials is it prompting me for?

How can I get past this?

Here's the client config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>

            <endpoint address="../Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here's the web config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpStreamingBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client />

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
      <service name="CitationAir.MissionPlanning.WebService.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpStreamingBinding"
            contract="CitationAir.MissionPlanning.WebService.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Windows Authentication`, you will get a password prompt if `Integrated Windows Authentication` is turned off`, which can be because you are using a browser other than Internet Explorer.

The password wont work if your `account is locked out`, if you are connecting to a service in an `untrusted domain`, or if your account does not have sufficient `permissions` to access the resource.

Could it be any of those in this case?